# Where are Africa's 600 million hectares of arable land located?

Tags: soil

According to [Africas Ministers pledge to commercialise regions agricultural sector](https://agrf.org/africas-ministers-pledge-to-commercialise-regions-agricultural-sector/)

> Speaking during a ministerial roundtable meeting at the AGRF in Kigali, Rwanda, the leaders noted that the economic health of the continent lies in the ability to earn from its biggest natural resource – land. Africa has 600 million hectares of uncultivated arable land, which is roughly 60 percent of the global total.

How are this 600 million hectares land distributed among the countries? I'm specifically asking for how many hectares of arable land each of Africa's 54 country has.

Comment: if i ask you to make 54 questions about this do you still think it is a small number?

Comment: Not a fair comparison at all. If someone knows a compiled stats in the form of a chart made by some organization (which there are in many cases), then it is a simple question.

Comment: you can find all the details about this here https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/AG.LND.ARBL.ZS?view=map to find more details you need to use the links on the right side on the page.(what is in use and what might be used)